# MongoDB (v:6) not creating timeseries collection (using mongoose v:7)

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, time-series

MongoDB is not creating time-series collection, using mongoose despite setting everything according to mongoose docs

```
const schema: Schema = new Schema(
  {
    userId: { type: String, required: true },
    time: { type: Date, required: true },
    value: { type: Number, required: true },
  },
  {
    timeseries: {
      timeField: 'time',
      metaField: 'value',
      granularity: 'minutes',
    },
    autoCreate: false,
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
  }
);
```

How do i know that the collection made is not time-series ?
This is my dummy collection info which i made.

```
{
    name: 'dummy/hearts',
    type: 'collection',
    options: {},
}
```

However a time series collection has the following options object

```
{
    name: 'test/hearts',
    type: 'timeseries',
    options: { timeseries: [Object] },
}
```